# Disable grey selection on not focused listview

Tags: css, listview, javafx

In my application I have multiple listviews. When I select a cell in one of the listviews, all the selected cells in the other listviews are grey (to indicate that they were selected in their listview). I've been trying to find out how to disable the "grey selector", so that we just see a listview as if it had only just been created.

At the moment, it is clear to me that they "grey selector" is part of the normal, not focused, behaviour (see the image). So my idea is to define different colours for a selected listcell when its listview is focused, or when its listview isn't focused. But I haven't found anything to distinguish this difference (using CSS).

[image]

Comment: show your code. then i will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `modena.css` file you can find following selectors to change colors of selected cells:

```
/* Selected rows */
.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar, 20%);
}

/* Selected when control is not focused */
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar-non-focused;
    -fx-table-cell-border-color: derive(-fx-selection-bar-non-focused, 20%);
}
```

Just change `-fx-background` to `-fx-background-color` and choose your color. Note that this solution will change colors in all `ListViews` in application.

Comment: Thanks! I set the `-fx-background-color` to `inherit`, this displays the original colour of the `ListCell`. So far, this is good. But the background colour is white, for all the cells. So the odd cells (which originally look light grey) look white as well... Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: Use `odd` PseudoClass of `list-cell`: `.list-cell:odd {
    -fx-background: -fx-control-inner-background-alt;
}`

Comment: Yup, adding `.list-cell:filled:selected:odd {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-control-inner-background-alt;
}` did the trick!